# Core Data Theory

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and have been working through a RestKit & Core Data tutorial ([here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/)) & the RKCatalog sample project.  I'm trying to understand the relationship between the xcdatamodeld file and the sqlite database.  Should the entities be designed using the xcdatamodeld and then call Create NSManaged SubClass for each entity before using the RKManagedObjectMapping?  The RKManagedObjectStore is then responsible for creating a sqlite database?